# Deeply-placed array contents were missing

Tags: arrays, json, ionic-framework

I was using ionic to get the contents of an array that is inside a JSON object that is inside of an array from [here](http://eventoserver-ecinauce.rhcloud.com/songwol/services). Here is part of the entire JSON object:

```
{
"services": [
{
  "id": 3,
  "info": null,
  "name": "singer",
  "owner": 1,
  "packages": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "package": "5 hours",
      "price": 400
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "package": "3 days",
      "price": 4000
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "package": "1 week",
      "price": 12000
    }
  ],
  "reviews": [],
  "type": "performer"
},
//...
```

The array of packages should have contents, but for some reason, the array is empty. Here is the controller to display the needed things:

```
.controller('ServiceCtrl', function($scope, Auth, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
var username = Auth.getUser();
$scope.userID = Auth.getId();

$http.get('http://eventoserver-ecinauce.rhcloud.com/' + username + '/services/' + $stateParams.serviceId)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.selectedService = data;
    $scope.serviceName = data.service[0].name;
    $scope.serviceType = data.service[0].type;
    $scope.ownerId = data.service[0].owner;
    $scope.packages = data.service[0].packages;
    console.log(data.service[0].packages.length);
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
  $scope.services = data;
});
})
```

In Ionic, the packages were displayed as

```
[]
```

Why are the array contents missing?

Comment: try declaring $scope.packages = [];  before   $http.get

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your `$http.get` success callback. It's `services` and not `service`:

```
$http.get('http://eventoserver-ecinauce.rhcloud.com/' + username + '/services/' + $stateParams.serviceId)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.selectedService = data;
    $scope.serviceName = data.services[0].name;
    $scope.serviceType = data.services[0].type;
    $scope.ownerId = data.services[0].owner;
    $scope.packages = data.services[0].packages;
    console.log(data.services[0].packages.length);
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
  $scope.services = data;
});
```